# Query to find if a value in one DE column is present in comma separated string from different DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have 2 data extensions, in first DE I have a column called 'Products' (which holds only one product name) against a customer record  and there's second DE which has a column called 'ProductRange' which holds multiple product names in comma separated values like "ABC;XYZ;GQH" against a customer record.
I need to find if a customer record with a specific product name in first DE is present in second DE with the same product name in the ProductRange column. Eg:

[image]

The output should be "CU002"

Answer (score 2):

If your products have consistent length in their IDs. Try something like this:

```
SELECT
a.CustomerId 
FROM DE1 AS a
INNER JOIN DE2 AS b
ON a.CustomerId = b.CustomerId
WHERE CHARINDEX(a.Product, b.ProductRange) > 0
```

Try yourself: https://dbfiddle.uk/GIyl7RMg

If not, try this:

```
SELECT
a.CustomerId 
FROM DE1 AS a
INNER JOIN DE2 AS b
ON a.CustomerId = b.CustomerId
WHERE CHARINDEX(CONCAT(a.Product, ' '), REPLACE(b.ProductRange, ';', '')) > 0
```

That's all I can think of at the moment

Comment: Thanks a lot @Duc, this seems to be working! But now when I am trying to do reverse its not giving exact results.
Eg: I want to exclude the matching results and only consider those contacts which are not present in another DE with the same product code. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: @ShantanuPunekar the simplest way is you use  a query to select the customer IDs who not in the result of the query above